# Injecting secrets from CI with GCP AppEngine's app.yml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration

Thanks for your help in advance!

I'm trying to create a simple but secure way to inject secrets from a commandline call to `gcloud app deploy app.yml`.

I'm relying on secret information stored in environment variables in my app's runtime, which I can set using the following `app.yml`:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

env_variables:
  SECRET_KEY: "passed-in-value"
```

For example, I'd like to be able to do something like

`SECRETKEY=${LOCAL_SECRET_VALUE} gcloud app deploy app.yml`

or use a cli argument if there is one, but I don't see any [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy).

At the end of the day, I just need a simple way to inject secrets so I can deploy to my testing environment from my local machine, or to production from a github action. I could just write the `app.yml` dynamically from my ci script and inject local environment variables, but it seems like there must be a more canonical way.

I can set environment variables with app.yml using the following syntax.

I would like a solution which works with both standard and flex app engine if possible.

Comment: What is the problem, I didn't get it. Are trying to do it remotely without kubectl? You call the kubeserver api in that case https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#secret-v1-core.

Comment: I'm not a nodejs expert but the simple thing that comes to mind is, why don't you just find and replace basic placeholders in your .yaml file while you make your pipeline run ? Also .. I think I'll also consider in storing the secret elsewhere, like in the datastore or the new gcp configuration management

Comment: Secret manager has been rolled out to beta last week, but libraries aren't yet finished. Official announcement soon. It will solve your issue!

Comment: @Pievis Yeah, that's my current solution. Just seems like there would be an easier way to specify environment variables via the command-line.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere That's great news, I'd definitely wait for it. Do you have a link?

Comment: Sure. Here: https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks!! I see that this will allow me to create secrets, but how will I be able to access them within an App Engine instance? Or should I just wait for it to come out to see? (Also, if you make this an answer instead of a comment, I'll happily mark it correct!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud has silently released in Beta [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/). The APIs are available but the client libraries aren't yet. The service will be announced soon and will help you to manage your secrets.

The principle is simple: In your yaml files and in your GIT, you simply save a reference to the secret, for example `mySecret#2` where 2 is the version number, and mySecret the name of your secret.

Then, perform a simple call to the API to get access to the secret

```
https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<myProject>/secrets/<MySecret>/versions/<Version>:access
```

The call must be secured with a `Bearer` access token in the header. Be sure that the App Engine service account has the [required roles](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control) (default service account: `YOUR_PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`), at least `roles/
secretmanager.secretAccessor`

*Note: I don't know how the library will be implemented if you request the secret without giving an explicit version. Is the 1st version which will be taken? the lastest?*

For now, there is a lot of manual overhead (get the token, build the URL, manage errors,...). If you can wait a couple of weeks, the life will be easier with client libraries!